# How to fix error: cannot find symbol method getSharedPreferences(Switch,int)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save state of switch, but this error appears

> error: cannot find symbol method getSharedPreferences(Switch,int).

How do I fix it?

My code:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(sw1, 0);
boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("switchkey", false);
sw1.setChecked(silent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a good idea after a cache invalidation to do a gradle sync and wait for Android Studio to finish the reindexing. After these, do a build, this should fix the problem in most cases.